# Android change video Recording Format?

Tags: android

Is there any way to change video Recording type in android? I have sony ericsson Xperia I want to change video recording  type in  .Mp4,And its Record in .3gp

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `setVideoEncoder()` method of the `MediaRecorder`. See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html.

Comment: I use this Intent for video recording ,,,,  Intent intent = new Intent(
         Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       intent.setType("video/*");
       startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_VIDEO);